# jpql statement syntax error, not a valid conditional expression

Tags: jpql

when EclipseLink execute this query, giving the error:

````
[175, 423] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.```

EclipseLink version is 2.7.4, use PostgreSQL database. run at Tomcat 9.0.20

welcome any propose

chang com.baremind.utils.JPAEntry.GroupCount to com.baremind.utils.JPAEntry$GroupCount (the GroupCount is inner class), but error is same

the whole method is
```java
    public static <T extends IDEntity> List<GroupCount> groupCount(Class<T> type, String conditions, String groupColumn) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager(type);
        String groupCountQuery = String.format("SELECT NEW %s(o.%s, COUNT(o)) FROM %s o WHERE %s GROUP BY o.%s", GroupCount.class.getName().replace('$', '.'), groupColumn, type.getSimpleName(), conditions, groupColumn);
        TypedQuery<GroupCount> q = em.createQuery(groupCountQuery, GroupCount.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
````

execute em.createQuery will throw error.

Comment: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT NEW com.baremind.utils.JPAEntry.GroupCount(o.objectId, COUNT(o)) FROM Log o WHERE o.objectType = 'article' AND o.objectId IN (SELECT c.id FROM NonContentArticle c WHERE c.lastUpdateTime > '2019-05-29 10:21:00' AND c.commentTime > '2019-05-30 09:21:00' AND c.state & (1 << 20) = 0 AND c.state & (1 << 21) = 0 AND c.state & (1 << 22) = 0 AND c.state & 1 != 0 AND c.state & (1 << 1) != 0 AND c.state & (1 << 2) != 0) AND o.action = 'read' GROUP BY o.objectId]. 
[175, 423] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
the not paste content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPQL **doesn't** support bit-shift operator at all.
This is the reason